# How can I translate text input in AngularFire2 Firestore use ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, angular6, angularfire2, ngx-translate

```
<div class="row"><h6>{{item.ageList}}</h6></div>
<div class="row"><h6>{{item.amenities}}</h6></div>
```

**Note: I wanna translate data after getting of Firestore such as**

```
<div class="row"><h6>{{'item.ageList' | translate}}</h6></div>
<div class="row"><h6>{{'item.amenities' | translate}}</h6></div>
```

[Firestore object image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQlwr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ngx-translate`'s repo you do have Firebase's example.
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/FIREBASE_EXAMPLE.md

**EDIT.**
After put some work I can give you working example.
**1. Put your firebase's config into `envrionment.ts`**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: ''
  },
};
```

You can get it from Firebase Console of your project.
**2. Create `firestore-trans-loader.ts` in `shared` directory, next to `app` directory**

```js
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class FirestoreTransLoader implements TranslateLoader {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  getTranslation(lang: string, prefix: string = 'translates'): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.doc(`${prefix}/${lang}`).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

**3. Prepare your `app.module.ts`** .

```js
export function FirestoreTranslationsLoaderFactory(db: AngularFirestore) {
  return new FirestoreTransLoader(db);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: FirestoreTranslationsLoaderFactory, deps: [AngularFirestore]}
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**4. And finally use it in your component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p>{{ helloKey | translate }}</p>
    <select (change)="onLangChange($event)">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="pl">Polish</option>
    </select>

  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  helloKey = 'HELLO';
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');
  }

  onLangChange(event) {
    this.translate.use(event.target.value);
  }

}
```

Here you do have complete repo without config where you can find out details (if I forgot about something).
https://github.com/Mr-Eluzive/angularfire-ngx-translate-example
Also I have put some work into this so maybe I will try to push it into `ngx-translate` repo.

Comment: Error in import { FirebaseTransLoader } from './shared/firebase-trans-loader';

Comment: @Omar And do you create and implement this file in this location?

Comment: Ok... then just give me a second, I will try provide you some complete example.

Comment: Just let me know whether my more descriptive explanation will try out helpful.

Comment: Ok, maybe it would be helpful for someone. I don't really understand what do you mean by 'data of firestore'... You want to use it like Google Translate or what?

Comment: Thank you very much, first time I didn't understand your code after check your answer correct :D

Comment: It's great that it turned out to be helpful :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621942/how-can-i-use-two-translators-one-for-json-file-and-firestore please I have new error