# How can I use two translators first for JSON file and second for firestore?

Tags: angular, angular6, angularfire2, ngx-translate

**JSON File Method**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

**JSON File Loader**

```
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
              deps: [HttpClient]
          }
      }),
```

**AngularFirestore Method**

```
export function FirestoreTranslationsLoaderFactory(db: AngularFirestore) {
  return new FirestoreTransLoader(db);
}
```

**AngularFirestore File Loader**

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
           provide: TranslateLoader,
           useFactory: FirestoreTranslationsLoaderFactory, 
           deps: [AngularFirestore]
        }
    }),
```

**Note: I can't use two same time I try to merge in one method and Loader.**

Comment: Yeah, like you said you can't use two at the same time. And maybe you should ask yourself if you really need this. I think that storing theoritically one piece of data separately in two places is not the best idea. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: JSON file ===> HTML Data ex: 'nameLabel or placeholder' and TranslateFirestore after get data of input text . ex:'input text' 'Variable'

Comment: But you can also put these things into firestore ( in the teams we always used to done that in this way ) and then if you want to change something you don't have to create PR, run CI/CD etc. just change in firestore.

Comment: But if you need this because of some reasons, you can use `MissingTranslationHandler` from ngx-translate

Comment: How can I connect that with my problem ? can you give me answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I have already answered you in the comments section:

> I think that storing theoretically one piece of data separately in two places is not the best idea.

But if you need something like that you can use `MissingTranslationHandler` like I have done here:
https://github.com/Mr-Eluzive/angularfire-ngx-translate-example/tree/missing-translation-handler
You can check out diffs between this branch and master to get familiar with what has to bo done to make it works.

Comment: How can I use translate *ngFor in this case?

Comment: <span translate>linksNav.{{i}}.item</span>

Comment: `translate` is pipe. It means that you have to use it with string. So when you iterate through your array then use `translate` on particular items in this array which are strings. If you do have some additional questions please create new question where you can place some code snippet and send me some url to this.